# Irerate over package_data files and copy them to current working directory

Tags: python, pip, package, resources, setuptools

## Background

I'm developing a python package with roughly the following directory structure:

```
mossutils/
  setup.py
  mossutils/
    __init__.py
    init.py
    data/
      style.css
      script.js
      ...
```

My package's `setup.py` declares `console_scripts` and includes `package_data` files:

```
setup(
  name='mossutils',
  packages=['mossutils'],
  package_data={"mossutils": ["data/*"]},
  entry_points = {
    "console_scripts": ['mu-init = mossutils.init:main']
  },
  ...)
```

Installing the package via `pip install` works as expected: everything is installed in my Python's `Lib\site-packages`, including the `data` directory and all files in it, and script `mu-init` can be executed from the shell (or rather, command prompt, since I'm using Windows).

## Goal

Script `mu-init` is supposed to do some kind of project scaffolding in the current working directory it is invoked from. In particular, it should copy all `package_data` files (`data/style.css`, `data/script.js`, ...) to the current directory.

## Solution Attempt

Using module [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html), I can read the content of a file, e.g.

```
import pkgutil
...
data = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, "data/style.css")
```

## Questions

1. Is there a way for my `init.py` script to *iterate* over the contents of the `data` directory, *without hard-coding* the file names (in `init.py`)?
2. Can the files from the `data` directory be *copied* to the current working directory, *without* opening the source file, reading the content, and writing it to a destination file?

Comment: "*Can the files … be copied … without opening, reading … and writing*" No, because this is the only way to copy files. But you're not obliged to do it yourself. [`shutil.copy2(src, dst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) can do it for you.

Comment: @phd Don't `shutil`'s `copy` functions take paths to files as arguments? How do I get a path to a `package_data` file?

Comment: There is an example at the very end of [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html).

Comment: That examples provides intuition for how `get_data` *could* be implemented, for a special case. I don't see how it is relevant here.

Comment: You want to copy data using, perhaps, ` shutil.copy2`. The example shows how to get the path to directory `data` so you can copy files.

Comment: @phd It really doesn't: it shows a piece of code "roughly equivalent" to `get_data` for the *special case* of "packages located in the filesystem, which have already been imported". `pkgutil.get_data` exists because it works in other cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files in the directory using `pkg_resources` library, which is distributed together with `setuptools`.

```py
import pkg_resources

pkg_resources.resource_listdir("mossutils", "data")
```